# c++ public function syntax error

Tags: c#, c++, reflector, code-translation

I am attempting to convert a c# to c++ with reflector. The code compiled, disassembled and reconstructed code is generating this error:

> 1>c:\users\user\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2008\projects\reflect_readoo\reflect_readoo\readoo.cpp(2)
>   : error C2059: syntax error : 'public'
>
> 1>c:\users\user\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2008\projects\reflect_readoo\reflect_readoo\readoo.cpp(2)
>   : error C2143: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before '{'
>
> 1>c:\users\user\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2008\projects\reflect_readoo\reflect_readoo\readoo.cpp(2)
>   : error C2447: '{' : missing function
>   header (old-style formal list?)

As I am unfamiliar with C++ syntax I'm not 100% sure where to start with these errors. The first the thing I tried was to remove all of the complicated code and just let the whole thing (it's one class in a namespace) be just a cout << "test"; in the namespace and class. removed the "ref" keyword, which removed the top error (this causes a million new errors wwith all of the functions in place) , but then was told a could only use a namespace if compiled with the clr flag, which would somewhat defeat the point of what i'm trying to do.

Can anyone recommend a path of testing that I could head down to start with? Otherwise, can anyone recommend a better way to translate a windows.form c# program into unmanaged c++? Should I just do it myself? (I want to do this eventually anyway, but it'd be a huge help to just have the damn thing and be able to look through and quickly see the differences, and I need the program for myself asap).

Thank you so much for any help, advice or guidance.

I understand the difficulty with the presentation side, I actually was not expecting for that to work, I just asked out of a dreamy hope. However, I would like to translate the "backend" of the application that was originally a console app. that I simply added as a class file to my windows form design. It's only this class of about a 1000 lines.

snippet:

```
public ref class RProgram {
    public:
        static System::String ^KeywordsLog = "Keywords.log"; // WHERE THE PROGRAM KEEPS ITS LOG

// classes. . . functions. . . the errors are reported on the first lines

};
```

**for that then I  understand, and concede the impossibility I suppose then, but could someone be so kind as to please help me resolve the errors preventing its compilation as managed c++?**

Comment: Could you list a snippet of the generated C++? It sounds like something pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have a very difficult time translating any reasonable complex **Windows Forms** application from C# to **unmanaged** C++.

You will not have access to any of the .NET framework libraries, which means no Windows Forms.  You'll need to choose a different API for your windowing, such as MFC.

In general, this means that you'll need to completely rearchitect your applicaiton - at least the presentation side of it.  My normal rule of thumb would be not to bother doing this - you have a working application, just keep it.

Comment: +1 Yep, looks like your tool is designed to convert to C++/CLI, not unmanaged C++.